# Nexus S and a NFC reader

Tags: nfc, nexus-s

I am sitting here with an ACS contactless reader ACR122 which is a NFC-reader/terminal. From my android app I want to send data to this reader, by creating two separate applications, one for the laptop and one app for the phone. For the application which should run one the computer I've been using the javax.smartcardio library. So my question is: Can I interact this way? Cuz I read one different forums that android doesn't support the javax.smartcardio library, but I guess this is just for the android SDK, am I right?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can interact in a way you have mentioned. The ACR122 can communicate in a p2p mode with the Nexus S, but it will not be that easy, because you have to implement or port couple of things. Look e.g. here:

http://www.libnfc.org/community/topic/401/p2p-communication-between-android-phone-and-nfc-reader/

BR
Petr